# Disable the 7-Zip program?

Tags: windows-8, 7-zip

I would like to know if there is a way to disable the factory-installed 7-Zip program? I downloaded WinZip to replace 7-Zip, which for some reason wouldn't open zip files when I went to use it.

Comment: Try the Control Panel --> Programs and Feature --> Uninstall 7 Zip, reboot, and then try again. If needed uninstall WinZip and reinstall it after 7 Zip is uninstalled

Comment: I wonder if you haven't made a mistake while writing this question. You said you want to _uninstall 7-Zip_ and install WinZip? Shouldn't you __uninstall WinZip__ and install 7-Zip? To clarify: WinZip a commercial app that asks you for money to give you the feature that Windows already has. 7-Zip is the best compression app on the planet.

Comment: Can you clarify WinZip not opening zip files?  Is it that the .zip extension is associated with 7-Zip so that gets called rather than WinZip, or WinZip doesn't work when you open it directly?  Uninstalling 7-Zip should have no bearing on whether WinZip works.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to uninstall 7-Zip like any other program. Just go to **Control Panel → Programs → Programs and Features**, select **7-Zip**, and click **Uninstall**

[image: Uninstalling 7-Zip]